# Django: Get model fields recursively (ForeignKeys and it's fields) as strings into a 1 level list

Tags: python, django, algorithm, recursion

I building a project in Django that needs to list all fields from a given model as options of a html select tag.
I wrote a recursive function that reads the model and returns a list with all fields and subfields. Like this:

```
def get_fields_true_hierarchy(model, list_fields = []):
    fields_obj = model._meta.fields
    for field_obj in fields_obj:
        if field_obj.rel:
            dict_fields = {field_obj.attname: []}
            list_fields.append(dict_fields)
            get_fields_true_hierarchy(field_obj.rel.to, dict_fields[field_obj.attname])
        else:
            list_fields.append(field_obj.attname)
    return list_fields
```

It returns an object such as the following:

```
fiedls = [
    'id', 
    'title', 
    'number', 
    'start_date', 
    'finish_date', 
    {'status_id':
        ['id', 
        'name']
    }, 
    'postal_code', 
    {'requestor_id': 
        ['id', 
        {'user_id': 
            ['id', 
            'password', 
            'last_login', 
            'is_superuser', 
            'username', 
            'first_name', 
            'last_name', 
            'email', 
            'is_staff', 
            'is_active', '
            date_joined']
        }, 
        'name', 
        'phone', 
        'email',  
        'contact_name', 
        'contact_email']
    }, 
    {'reason_id': 
        ['id', 
        'description']
    }, 
    'details', 
    {'group_id': 
        ['id', 
        'description']
    }, 
    {'subgroup_id': 
        ['id', 
        'description']
    }, 
    {'manager_id': 
        ['id', 
        'password', 
        'last_login', 
        'is_superuser', 
        'username', 
        'first_name', 
        'last_name', 
        'email', 
        'is_staff', 
        'is_active', 
        'date_joined']
    }, 
    'datetime_subscription', 
    'allowed', 
    'data_def'
]
```

However, I need to get a single level list which would look like this:

```
fiedls = [
    'id', 
    'title', 
    'number', 
    'start_date', 
    'finish_date', 
    'status_id',
    'status_id.id', 
    'status_id.name', 
    'postal_code', 
    'requestor_id',
    'requestor_id.id', 
    'requestor_id.user_id',
    'requestor_id.user_id.id', 
    'requestor_id.user_id.password', 
    'requestor_id.user_id.last_login', 
    'requestor_id.user_id.is_superuser',
    'requestor_id.user_id.username', 
    'requestor_id.user_id.first_name', 
    'requestor_id.user_id.last_name', 
    'requestor_id.user_id.email', 
    'requestor_id.user_id.is_staff', 
    'requestor_id.user_id.is_active',
    'requestor_id.user_id.date_joined',
    'requestor_id.name', 
    'requestor_id.phone', 
    'requestor_id.email',  
    'requestor_id.contact_name', 
    'requestor_id.contact_email',
    'reason_id',
    'reason_id.id', 
    'reason_id.description',
    'details',
    'group_id', 
    'group_id.id', 
    'group_id.description',
    'subgroup_id',
    'subgroup_id.id', 
    'subgroup_id.description',
    'manager_id', 
    'manager_id.id',
    'manager_id.password', 
    'manager_id.last_login', 
    'manager_id.is_superuser', 
    'manager_id.username', 
    'manager_id.first_name', 
    'manager_id.last_name', 
    'manager_id.email', 
    'manager_id.is_staff', 
    'manager_id.is_active', 
    'manager_id.date_joined',
    'datetime_subscription', 
    'allowed',
    'data_def'
]
```

I couldn't write a recursive function to return such result. Do you have any ideas on how to perform this task?
I'm stuck on this function below. But it does not behave as expected.

PS.: `list_fields` argument will come from the `get_fields_true_hierarchy()` function.

```
def get_fields_fake_hierarchy(list_fields, fake_hierarchy = [], parent_str = "", reset=True):
    for field in list_fields:
        if reset:
            parent_str = ""
        if isinstance(field, dict):
            for key, value in field.iteritems():
                fake_hierarchy.append(key)
                parent_str += "."+key
                get_fields_fake_hierarchy(value, fake_hierarchy, parent_str, reset=False)
        else:
            fake_hierarchy.append("%s.%s"%(parent_str, field))
    fake_hierarchy = [i[1:] if i[0]=='.' else i for i in fake_hierarchy]
    return fake_hierarchy
```

Comment: A proper programming approach I would use, would be to create a separate Class Foo with all those attributes, fetch the results and create the mock object which in turn you shall use in the views.
The idea is to fetch all the necessary data, parse and create the mock object, if those are expensive operations you can cache the object and re-create it when necessary. If parsing requires effort, create a separate parser function or class, let it construct the object and return it back to the view.

Comment: I don't think that would be possible once this object will have different sizes according to the model the user selects on the interface. It's actually a plugin that reads whatever models the user has on the project, so I couldn't predict it's attributes.

Comment: @Mauricio: Python is highly dynamic so from a technical POV it _is_ actually possible to either add attributes to an instance or even create full classes at runtime. Now whether it's a good idea really depends on your use case - as far as I'm concerned, if all I need is a list of (possibly dotted) names, the "proper programming approach" is to use a list of (possibly dottted) names.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers. I understand what you mean. Regarding to the need of a flat list, It's necessary cause a need them on a html select tag. The app I'm building is a dynamic report tool that gets the selected model fields into a select tag. After selecting the field the user would select a filter_type (exact, iexact, contains, etc) and a value. Than a have a method called get_results() which builds a dict ({'user__name__exact': 'Mathew'}). With that dict  I do objects.filter(**filter_dict). I need to have a flat list in orde put it in a form, and than use it to build the queryset parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a recursive generator instead, and prefix the names on the fly:

```
def do_prefix(name, prefix):
    if prefix:
        return "%s.%s" % (prefix, name)
    return name

def get_fields_flat(model):
    return [name for name in iter_fields(model)]

def iter_fields(model, prefix=None):
    fields = model._meta.fields
    for field in fields:
        name = do_prefix(field.attname, prefix)
        yield  name
        if field.rel:
            rel = field.rel.to
            for f in iter_fields(rel, name):
                yield f
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! It really did the trick. Guess I have to work a lot harder to be a real programer.

Comment: hahaha seriously now, don't judge yourself based on other people's skills, everyone has it's own pace and the only way to gather experience doing your own stuff. You're in the right way, give it some time and you'll be fine :)